# Delay output from swift service class using callback

Tags: ios, swift

Hi i am studying swift

i have following block of code which is not compiling

```
class UserService {

    func name(delay: Int, completion: ([User]) -> Void) {
        var users = [User]()


        users.append(User(name: "User 1", email:"user1@gmail.com", age: 25))
        users.append(User(name: "User 2", email: "user2@gmail.com", age: 26))
        users.append(User(name: "User 3", email: "user3@gmail.com", age: 27))

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay, execute: completion(users))
    }
}
```

I want to delay output after certain, new to this syntax i want to know how can this callback be invoked after certain time. This result i want to deliver on MainThread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Swift 3 this is very easy:

```
let seconds = 10
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) {
    // Some work
}
```

In your case it would be:

```
class UserService {

    func name(delay: DispatchTime, completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
        var users = [User]()


        users.append(User(name: "User 1", email:"user1@gmail.com", age: 25))
        users.append(User(name: "User 2", email: "user2@gmail.com", age: 26))
        users.append(User(name: "User 3", email: "user3@gmail.com", age: 27))

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay) {
            completion(users)
        }
    }
}

// Test it
let service = UserService()
let delay: DispatchTime = .now() + 10
service.name(delay: delay) { users in
    print(users)
}
```

Comment: DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: completion(users)) says /UserService.swift:24:28: Cannot invoke 'asyncAfter' with an argument list of type '(deadline: _, execute: Void)'

Comment: See my updated answer. You can't call  `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: delay, execute: completion(users))`, because `execute` parameters is of type `() -> Void`, not `([User]) -> Void`

Comment: Instead of having the `name` function take a delay that's a DispatchTime, I would suggest having it take a delay that is a TimeInterval, and doing the ".now() + dispatchTime" calculation in the call to `asyncAfter`. The term "delay" suggests an amount of time to wait, not a time to fire. (DispatchTime is an absolute system time in the future. That's why the parameter to `asyncAfter` is named `deadline`.)